# Couldnt play the audio file uploaded from android to node.js server

Tags: android, node.js, multipart

I have tried uploading an audio file from android to node.js server,but unfortunately file uploaded in the server is not playing. It shows the error "No suitable decoder module: VLC does not support the audio or video format 'samr'" while playing in VLC media player.

This is my Android code:

```
                String name = aurl[0];
                String groupid = aurl[0];
                File file = new File(aurl[1]);
                //ByteArrayBody byteArrayBody = new ByteArrayBody(audioData, name);
                MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                //multipartEntity.addPart("uploadDocument", byteArrayBody);
                ContentBody cb = new FileBody(file,"video/mp4");
                multipartEntity.addPart("uploadDocument",cb);
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                System.out.println("Befor Call ...................................");
                String requestUri = Constants.URI_SERVER + "/upload/"+ groupid +"/FromAndroidkycUploadingAudio";
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(requestUri);
                httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity);

                Header header = new BasicHeader(Constants.FIELD_REQUEST_SOURCE, Constants.FIELD_ANDROID);
                httpPost.addHeader(header);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                if(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) { 
                    toastMsg = Constants.MSG_UPLOAD_SUCCESS;
                } else {
                    toastMsg = Constants.MSG_UPLOAD_FAILURE;
                }
```

My server side Node.js Code:

```
            var fs1=require('fs');
            var util = require('util');
            var is = fs1.createReadStream(req.files.uploadDocument.path)
            var os = fs1.createWriteStream("client_documents/"+"Audio1"+".mp4");
                util.pump(is, os, function() {
                        //fs1.unlinkSync(req.files.uploadDocument.path);
                        console.log('It\'s moved!');
                    });
```

Please suggest me any solution...

Comment: What exactly does not work? What error do you get?

Comment: Uploaded audio file is not playing.

Comment: Does the file size match the uploaded one? What did you use for playing. In the current state this question just leaves every one else guessing.

Comment: File Size is same only. I am playing using VLC Media player